# How to run this program which read excel using POI

Tags: java, eclipse

I've try to run this code in eclipse but I've get this: selection does not contain a main type eclipse.
Does anyone know how I will do it? I am newbie in java and I need help!
The program I try to make is to read excel file using POI! :)

```
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.FileInputStream;    
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.Iterator;    
import java.util.List;    
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;    
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;    
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;    
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;    
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;    

public class sample2 {

private void sample2(test)

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(test);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

//Get iterator to all cells of current row
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();


 try {

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Iterate through each rows from first sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    //For each row, iterate through each columns
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
        }
       }
      System.out.println("");
  }
  file.close();
  FileOutputStream out = 
      new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run a Java application without a main method.

You need something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sample2 s = new sample2();
    s.sample();
}
```

Also your code contains a lot of errors. You are:

- Missing a main method
- Capitalization is wrong
- Miss types on the input argument for the sample2 method (String test?)
- The code is broken many ways. You duplicated the code to read files twice, for error handling, etc.

Reading a good tutorial on Java would help greatly here. A great tutorial on Java and Excel can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html), and pay some attention to the main method, that's the entry of your Java application.

Comment: I've change it and the result is:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method sample() is undefined for the type sample2

 at sample2.main(sample2.java:18)

Comment: Correct. It means the sample method doesn't exist without arguments. You need to remove the 'test' parameter as mentioned by 'javadev' below.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not compile due to the identifier "test" in the sample2 method. Remove it and to run the program :

Just add the following method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new sample2().sample2();
}
```